# Transaction created with sendtoaddress didn't propagate to the network, how to resend?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, sendtoaddress

i am running Bitcoin Core 0.14.1 on a  Centos6 Server.
I had several transactions (receive, send) in the last days, and everything was fine.

I always did my transaction with the bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress ADDRESS  AMOUNT ... and that worked fine. Always after some minutes i could see my unconfirmed transactions at Blockchain.info

But yesterday i made a new transaction same as always and i get an transactions id successfully, but i cant find my transaction in the Blockchain. And the receiver does not the transaction also.

What i have tried:

- I wait more than 24 hours ( but my transaction is not showing up in blockchain, and wasnt include in any block)
- I turned off the IP Tables and make sure that the Wallet is connected to the network.
- I stooped Bitcoin with bitcoin-cli stop and made an recan with bitcoind -rescan
- I stooped Bitcoin with bitcoin-cli stop and made an recan with bitcoind -zapwallettxes
- I deleted the memorypool.dat in .bitcoin directory
- I reload the complete Blockchain

Who has the solution?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve: Resending or recovering? Is the transaction still showing as unconfirmed on your server? Did the transaction get malleated and confirmed? Have you checked whether the transaction's inputs are still in your wallet? Did you delete the mempool file and do `-zapwallettxes` in the same go?

Comment: I've guessed at your goal to give the question a more speaking title. If I guessed wrong, please edit to improve. :)

Comment: The amount is subtracted from my balance and its shown in my wallet as unconfirmed transaction. I want to resend it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the transaction ID you can get the raw hex transaction via:

```
bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction <txid>
```

That will produce a rather long string `<rawtx>` which is the serialized transaction. You can then use

```
bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction <rawtx>
```

or any of the web interfaces that allow pushing a transaction (just search for `pushtx` and I'm sure you'll find a few providers). The raw transaction does not contain any private information. It is safe to publish, however services may attribute the transaction with your IP if you use them, so try `sendrawtransaction` first, which is the exact same behavior your client would use anyway.

Notice that your client will also automatically retry your wallet transactions every once in a while, so manual intervention may not be needed. It could be you haven't attached a large enough fee for the TX to be propagated in the network.

Answer (score 0):

Edit to the @cdecker answer.
I had the same problem using Bitcoin Core v22.0.0. My transaction wasn't send correctly because my proxy didn't work probably, but the transaction was already displayed in my wallet but never got sent to the bitcoin network. Even after fixing the network problem Bitcoin Core didn't resend the transaction.

If you're using the client version you can open the Console on the top and type the following without the bitcoin-cli to resend your transaction.

```
getrawtransaction <txid>

sendrawtransaction <rawtx>
```

[image]